# Why "time part" represents energy in Four-momentum?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, momentum, vectors

I was going through *Spacetime Physics* by Taylor and Wheeler and came to a point where they said, and I quote,

> In what follows we find that momenergy is indeed a four-dimensional
> arrow in spacetime, the momenergy 4-vector (Box 7-1). Its three "space
> parts" represent the momentum of the object in the three chosen space
> directions. Its "time part" represents energy. The unity of momentum
> and energy springs from the unity of space and time.

This part feels too abrupt for me and I am looking for a more elaborated explanation.

[Here](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/Spacetime_Physics_(Taylor_and_Wheeler)/07%3A_Momenergy/7.02%3A_Momenergy_Arrow) is a link to that chapter.

Comment: $p^0=\gamma m c=\frac{E}{c}$

Comment: Presumably, you seek an answer using the storyline that you are following,
as opposed to another viewpoint that develops relativity in a [possibly completely-] different way.

What did you think about the preceding subsection 7.1, particularly the Question and Answer?

Answer (score 15):

By [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) every continuous symmetry has a corresponding conserved quantity.

Energy is the conserved quantity corresponding to translation symmetry in the time direction of space-time. That's why energy is found in the "time part".

Likewise, the momentum in the $x$ direction is the conserved quantity corresponding to translation symmetry in the $x$ direction of space-time. That's why $p_x$ is found in the $x$ part.

In quantum physics, we have the formulas $p_x = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $E = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t},$ which also are related to this.

Comment: An explicit reference to Noether's theorem might be helpful here, to explain what you mean by "related to".

Answer (score 12):

$\vec{P}=(E,p_x,p_y,p_z)$ of an object are said to be the components of a 4-vector $\vec{P}$ because their values transform like a 4-vector when the object is boosted or rotated.

For example, suppose the initial object with energy and momentum $\vec{P}$ is boosted by $\lambda=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)$ in the $x$-direction. You will measure the new energy and momentum $\vec{P}\,'$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} E' \cr  p_x' \cr p_y' \cr p_z' \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh\lambda & \sinh\lambda & 0 & 0 \cr
\sinh\lambda & \cosh\lambda & 0 & 0 \cr
            0 &             0 & 1 & 0 \cr
            0 &             0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} E \cr  p_x \cr p_y \cr p_z \end{bmatrix}
$$
Energy and momentum are said to be a 4-vector **because** their measured values transform like this with a 4$\times$4 matrix. Time and space displacements $\vec{X}=(t,x,y,z)$ are also said to be a 4-vector **because** their values also transform like this with a 4$\times$4 matrix.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing to add to md2perpe's very good answer about time-translation, but you can also see that the zeroth component of the four-momentum is, to lowest order, (classical) kinetic energy plus rest energy.  The four-velocity is defined as:
$$
u^\mu = \frac{d x^\mu}{d\tau} = \left( \begin{array}{c}
\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\\
\frac{v_x}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\\
\frac{v_y}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\\
\frac{v_z}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\\
\end{array}
 \right)
$$
where $\beta^2 = v^2/c^2 = \frac{1}{c^2} \left( v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2\right)$. Defining the four-momentum as $p^\mu = m u^\mu$, we can then Taylor expand its first component about $\beta = 0$, to find:
$$
\begin{align}
p^0 & = \frac{mc}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}} \\
& = mc +  \left[ - \frac{1}{2} \frac{m c \left(-2 \beta \right)}{\left( 1 - \beta^2\right)^{3/2}} \right]_{\beta = 0} \left(\beta - 0 \right) \\
& \quad \quad + \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left(\cdots\right)(\beta)^2 + \frac{mc}{\left(1 - \beta^2\right)^{3/2}}\right]_{\beta=0} \left(\beta - 0\right)^2 +  O\left(\beta \right)^3 \\
& = \frac{1}{c}\left[ mc^2 + \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \right] + O\left(\beta\right)^3 
\end{align}
$$
So defining $E = c p^0$, we have:
$$
E = m c^2 + \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics, E is canonically conjugate to the time and p is canonically conjugate to the position. Consider a 4-vector made of some canonical variables, ($u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$, $u_4$). It can evolve according to the Hamiltonian $H(u_i)$ within its own frame.

Now view it in a frame that is travelling at velocity $\vec{v}$ with respect to the frame in which the canonical variables $u_i$ are measured. The Lorentz transform transforms the canonical variables to $\vec{u^\prime}$. In this reference frame, the Hamiltonian is $H(\vec{u^\prime})$ but because of the law that physical laws remain the same within each reference frame, the Hamiltonian takes the same form with respect to $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{u^\prime}$ for each $i$ in $u_i$

Since Hamiltons can be expressed in terms of canonically conjugate variables, as an alternative, within any reference frame, that means that the 4-vector ($w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, $w_4$) is another possible four vector that obeys the Lorentz symmetry, such that physical laws remain the same in transformed reference frames, if $\vec{w}$ is canonically conjugate to $\vec{u}$ for each $i$ in $u_i$.

E is canonically conjugate to t and p is canonically conjugate to x so (E, $\vec{p}$) is a four vector since (t, $\vec{x}$) is a four vector.